# Как подсчитать изображения, которые не поместились в div с overflow: hidden?

Tags: css, jquery, img, overflow

Знатоки, пожалуйста подскажите. Есть div высотой 400px с overflow: hidden, в нем 12 изображений, видны 9, а остальные обрезаны родительским div. Как подсчитать те 3 изображения, которые не поместились? Изображений в див может быть больше или меньше, т.к. они подгружаются динамически. Их visibility меняет статус, когда они выходят за пределы overflow: hidden? Выглядит это так:

[image: Выглядит это так:]

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.jpg" />
  <img src="4.jpg" />
  <img src="5.jpg" />
  <img src="6.jpg" />
  <img src="7.jpg" />
  <img src="8.jpg" />
  <img src="9.jpg" />
  <img src="10.jpg" />
  <img src="11.jpg" />
  <img src="12.jpg" />
  <img src="13.jpg" />
  <img src="14.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спрашивали про высоту, высота одинаковая, но ширина разная, из-за этого количество img тоже разное

Comment: Просто в качестве замечания: у картинок есть обязательный атрибут alt="", без него Ваша разметка невалидна

Comment: у меня совсем другой код, это в качестве примера, логика такая же.

Comment: Ребят, спасибо всем за помощь, humster_spb норм подсказал и вот еще хороший ответ https://toster.ru/q/640821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика может быть такой: определяете координаты нижней границы div'а, в цикле проходите по всем картинкам и если их offset().top больше нижней границы блока-обёртки, значит, они скрыты, и их надо посчитать:

```js
let bottom = $('#wrapper').offset().top+$('#wrapper').outerHeight();
let counter = 0;
$('.inner').each(function(){
  if($(this).offset().top > bottom) {
    counter++;
  }
})
console.log(counter)
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
}
.inner {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 28%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
  <div class="inner">6</div>
  <div class="inner">7</div>
  <div class="inner">8</div>
  <div class="inner">9</div>
  <div class="inner">10</div>
</div>
```